# bluebird: Cancel on promise.join doesn't cancel children

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, cancellation

I am using bluebird.js for a better promise object than jquery deferred objects. What I want to be able to do is run two requests in parallel and when they both finish then run some code. But I need both of these requests to be able to be cancelled. Below is some example code highlighting my problem. When I run this and call the cancel function on the joined promise I do hit the catch for the cancel exception that is on the join but not on firstPromise or secondPromise and so the ajax request does not get aborted. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

```
var firstAjax = someAjaxRequest();
var firstPromise = Promise.resolve(firstAjax)
.cancellable()
.catch(promise.CancellationError, function (e) {
    console.log("cancelled request");
    firstAjax.abort();
    throw e;
})
.catch(function (e) {
    console.log("caught " + e);
});

var secondAjax = someAjaxRequest();
var secondPromise = Promise.resolve(secondAjax)
.cancellable()
.catch(Promise.CancellationError, function (e) {
    secondAjax.abort();
    throw e;
})
.catch(function (e) {
    console.log("caught " + e);
});

var joinedPromise = Promise.join(firstPromise, secondPromise)
.cancellable()
.catch(Promise.CancellationError, function(e){
    firstPromise.cancel();
    secondPromise.cancel();
});

joinedPromise.cancel();
```

Comment: Your code is full with the deferred anti pattern, Any reason your secondPromise function isn't just `Promise.resolve(someAjaxRequest())` ?

Comment: Why are you twice calling `ajax.abort()`? You should have one `firstAjax.abort()` and one `secondAjax.abort()`!

Comment: I was using the anti pattern because I am a noob XD. Thanks for pointing that out. As for the double ajax.abort that was a typo, should have been firstAjax.abort and secondAjax.abort just like you mentioned. But even with these changes calling cancel on the join doesn't seem to be canceling the two promises that are joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/JHuJ3/

```
window.CancellationError = Promise.CancellationError;

var cancellableAjax = function() {
    var ret = $.ajax.apply($, arguments);
    return Promise.resolve(ret).cancellable().catch(CancellationError, function(e) {
        console.log("cancelled");
        ret.abort();
        throw e;
    });
};


var firstPromise = cancellableAjax();
var secondPromise = cancellableAjax();
var joinedPromise = Promise.join(firstPromise, secondPromise).cancellable().catch(CancellationError, function(e) {
    firstPromise.cancel();
    secondPromise.cancel();
});

Promise.delay(500).then(function() {
    joinedPromise.cancel(); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a great example of what I was trying to achieve. And yes it works.